# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia') at HTMLButtonElement.startRecording | .Net core using JS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, audio-recording, audiojs

***its not wokig on http how can i solve it please help me to resolve that.Its Perfectly woroking on localhost and not woking on Production/Live  Server
Showing Error :
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia') at HTMLButtonElement.startRecording***

```
 let audioBlob;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const startButton = document.getElementById('startRecord');
    const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopRecord');
    const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
    let mediaRecorder;
    let audioChunks = [];

    async function startRecording() {
        try {
            const stream = await  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                if (event.data.size > 0) {
                    audioChunks.push(event.data);
                }
            };

            mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

                // Preview the recorded audio
                audioPlayer.src = audioUrl;
                audioPlayer.play();

                // Send the audio data to the server
                // sendAudioToServer(audioBlob);
            };

            mediaRecorder.start();
            startButton.disabled = true;
            stopButton.disabled = false;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
        }
    }

    function stopRecording() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        startButton.disabled = false;
        stopButton.disabled = true;
    }

    startButton.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
    stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="startRecord" class="btn btn-success">Start Recording</button>
                <button id="stopRecord" class=" btn btn-danger" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
                <audio id="audioPlayer" controls></audio>
```

Comment: you can only use getUserMedia if secure.  (https)

Comment: Could you please format your code snippet accordingly? What issue you are having with?